# How to properly convert string with time from text file to time?

Tags: java

I use Calendar to get time. I want to get string from file(time) and parse it to calendar object. I will compare time from file and current time using `after();`  and `before();` method of Calendar class

If time from file is after current time -> print ("Time from file is after curretn time.

If time from file is before current time -> print ("Time from file is before

What I did:

- I Created file
- Got current time
- Parsed current time to a string
- Saved a string to a file
- Got current time
- Read etx from file
- Parsed text from file to Date object

Returned time from file is correct, but he problem is that parsed time from file return `Thu Jan 01 20:59:00 GMT+07:00 1970` not my current year

That's why if statement always return first argument

**How to properly parse time from file to make comparison of two object of time?**

Here is my full code:

```
public class Main {


  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ParseException {

    Calendar calNow = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date dateNow = new Date();
    calNow.setTime(dateNow);


    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 5);
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
    String formatted = df.format(cal.getTime());

    String formattedFut = df.format(calNow.getTime());

    Path file = Paths.get("testFile.txt");

    if (Files.exists(file) && Files.size(file) == 0) {

      Files.write(file, List.of(formatted));

    } 


    String timeFromFile = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("testFile.txt")));

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
    Date dateOld = sdf.parse(timeFromFile);
    Calendar calendarOld = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendarOld.setTime(dateOld);


    if (dateNow.after(dateOld)) {
      System.out.println(dateNow + " is after day from file");
    }

    if (dateNow.before(dateOld)) {
      System.out.println(dateNow + " is before day from file");

    }

  }

}
```

Comment: Do you use Java 8 or higher?

Comment: @achAmháin I use Java 10

Comment: how does the string in the file looks like???

Comment: text from file is : `20:59` I wrote current time in minutes and seconds in 24-hour format

Comment: use java.time.* time API instead of the obsolete java.util.Date related classes. Look it up.

Comment: thanx for your suggestions, but I found my own version)

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION FOUND:**

```
   public class Main {


   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ParseException {

 SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());


Calendar calendarNow = Calendar.getInstance();
Date dateNow = new Date();
calendarNow.setTime(dateNow);


Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 5);
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
String formatted = df.format(cal.getTime());

String formattedFut = df.format(calendarNow.getTime());

Path file = Paths.get("testFile.txt");

if (Files.exists(file) && Files.size(file) == 0) {

  Files.write(file, List.of(formatted));    
} 

Calendar calendarOld = Calendar.getInstance();
String timeFromFile = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("testFile.txt")));

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
calendarOld.setTime(sdf.parse(timeFromFile));

if (calendarNow.after(calendarOld)) {
  System.out.println(timeFromFile + " \ntime passed");
}

if (calendarNow.before(calendarOld)) {
  System.out.println(timeFromFile + " \n time NOT PASSED");

    }

  }

}
```